# I don't use TLS extensions, I'm safe of HeartBleed?

Tags: tls, heartbleed

I know that the vulnerability exploits the Heartbeat response which is a TLS feature. Now, when testing some of *my* important sites, there was some wording that scared me, [namely](http://possible.lv/tools/hb/?domain=www.banreservas.com.do):

> TLS extension 15 (heartbeat) seems disabled, so your server **is probably unaffected.**

Does that means that there's another possible vulnerability related to Heartbeat, or the wording is like that just to leave the possibility of other vulnerabilities and don't make me feel safe?

Comment: It's like anything in security.  The absence of a positive result does not prove a negative result.  It's still up to you if you want to check what implementation of TLS you're relying on.

Comment: @JohnDeters ok, but that means that those servers are safe of *that* vulnerability?

Comment: It only means they passed one specific test. Nobody can promise complete safety, ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These "heartbleed" testing services work by attempting to perform the OpenSSL TLS heartbeat exploit and seeing if it is successful.  There are three possible outcomes:

1) The server accepts the malformed "heartbeat" packet and drops it.  In this case, you can be reasonably certain the server is unaffected (or that a firewall or other service is protecting it).

2) The server accepts the packet and returns random memory contents in its response.  In this case, you know for certain that the server is vulnerable.

However, you're encountering another option:

3) The server states that it does not support the TLS heartbeat option.  It's reasonable to assume the server is safe, but you can't be certain.  It's possible, for example, that the server is using the vulnerable version of the OpenSSL library and can be tricked into accepting a TLS heartbeat packet.